# Search variable code to know the stop-loss of our trade of the day

Tags: pine-script

Search variable code to know the stop-loss of our trade of the day

It is not for a strategy but an indicator

Could you help me?

Thank you very much

I did not see anything in the pinescript tutorials that matched

Comment: What do you mean by variable code?

Comment: mean a code to know the stop-loss of our trade of the day

Answer (score 0):

No, in pinescript you can't retrieve the value of the stop loss used until you record it before enter the trade.